# Kubernetes Install of SOLR SearchStax Not Completing

Tags: solr, kubernetes

We are doing a `Kubernetes` install and the part of the `SOLR SearchStax` install the process is not completing. We get some Successful Creates, but also see an error that `BackOffLimitExceeded`. The job status stays at 0/1 completed and we notice the SOLR `Cores` are not created. Has anyone run into this issue? Is there a setting or kubectl command we need to run? We added the IP to the `SearchStax` deployment IP filter, but we are still running into the issue.

[image]

Here is the error we see in the log:

```
Invoke-RestMethod :
 Error 401 Authentication failed, Response code: 401
 HTTP ERROR 401
 Problem accessing /solr/admin/collections. Reason:
 Authentication failed, Response code: 401
At C:\Start.ps1:58 char:21
 + ... lections = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$SolrEndpoint/admin/collections?a ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
 pWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
 ll.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

The `solr-init` data initialization container script is failing while performing a request to get the list of collections from the Solr service:

```
$solrCollections = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$SolrEndpoint/admin/collections?action=LIST&omitHeader=true" -Method Get -Credential (Get-SolrCredential)).collections
```

You are getting a 401 HTTP status code, not a 404, so it seems that your Solr service is reachable, but it is failing on the authentication process.

The `Get-SolrCredential` function, used to build the value for the `-Credential` parameter in the failing GET request, returns a `$null` object with the default K8s configuration, because the `SOLR_USERNAME` and `SOLR_PASSWORD` environment variables are not defined as secrets in the `solr-init.yaml` deployment configuration and there are no secrets files for them in the `secrets` folder:

```
function Get-SolrCredential {
    if ($env:SOLR_USERNAME -and $env:SOLR_PASSWORD) {
        return New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:SOLR_USERNAME, (ConvertTo-SecureString $env:SOLR_PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force))
    }
    return $null
}
```

If your Solr service requires authentication credentials to access it, you need to create them in the `secrets` folder and define these two missing secrets in your `solr-init.yaml` K8s deployment configuration.

Comment: We just tried this. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Any special character in the password? This page might help on solving the 401 authentication error too: https://www.searchstax.com/docs/hc/unauthorized-error/

Comment: Ended up removing the username and password and used API keys instead. Now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What we ended up doing is removing the username and password and just using the API keys. It worked after that.

Comment: API Keys are used by the solr-init job only to deploy a new Solr core config. Disabling the Basic Authentication of your Solr instance is a workaround, but be sure to re-enable it again once the data initialization job runs successfully, if this is a production instance (see also https://www.searchstax.com/docs/security/#solrauth).

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroFaniuolo.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you have enabled basic authentication in SOLR. But the fix is easy, all you need to do is add the username and password in your SOLR connection strings.

The connection string in the K8s secret files needs to look like this:

https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@your-solr-endpoint.searchstax.com/solr;solrCloud=true

It is always a good idea to have authentication specially in prod environments, so before disabling the auth, try using that method. I tested it and it is working in Sitecore 10.1